# ToggleButton does not redraw if TextOn or TextOff are changed

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have mvvmcross project, a ToggleButton with bindings for Checked, TextOn, and TextOff properties. I set the texts for those programmatically, I see in the setter that RaisePropertyChanged() is called, but the button text in UI stays the same, unless I click on it or change value of the property bound to "Checked". Changing Checked seems like a workaround, but ugly, is there a proper way?

**FirstView.axml** contains
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/myBtn"
            local:MvxBind="TextOff MyBtnOFFLabel; TextOn MyBtnONLabel; Checked MyBtnChecked"
            android:textOff="OFF"
            android:textOn="ON"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:width="0dp" />

**FirstViewModel.cs** contains

```
private string myBtnOFFLabel;
public string MyBtnOFFLabel
{
    get { return myBtnOFFLabel; }
    set { myBtnOFFLabel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnOFFLabel); }
}
private string myBtnONLabel;
public string MyBtnONLabel
{
    get { return myBtnONLabel; }
    set { myBtnONLabel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnONLabel); }
}

public FirstViewModel()
{
  Global.EventSomethingChanged += Handler_SomethingChanged;
}

void Handler_SomethingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UpdateUI();
}

private void UpdateUI()
{
  MyBtnOFFLabel = "new OFF";
  MyBtnONLabel = "new ON";
}
```

**SecondViewModel.cs** contains

```
Global.FireEventSomethingChanged();
```

as expected, UpdateUI() is called in FirstViewModel.cs and it updates the label properties for myBtn (confirmed in debug mode), but when I close SecondViewModel in emulator I see the old label remaining in first view UI. If I click on that button, it switches to showing correct labels.

Comment: Some code, pictures, etc  would make it much easier to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sound like a bug in the component, you should file a bug report with mvvmcross project

Comment: hi Stuart, I've added some details, I hope it is reproducible

Comment: found another workaround: in UpdateUI() if I call RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnChecked); after assigning new labels, the UI gets updated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you needed to RaisePropertyChanged on your MyBtnChecked.  In your comment above you mention that adding it to UpdateUI() causes it to redraw properly.  That's not a "work around" per se as you need to put that somewhere.  You could also do this:

```
private string myBtnOFFLabel;
public string MyBtnOFFLabel
{
    get { return myBtnOFFLabel; }
    set { 
        myBtnOFFLabel = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnOFFLabel); 
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnChecked);
    }
}
private string myBtnONLabel;
public string MyBtnONLabel
{
    get { return myBtnONLabel; }
    set { 
        myBtnONLabel = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnONLabel); 
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyBtnChecked);
    }
}
```

As it sounds like your MyBtnChecked is dependent on changes to MyBtnOFFLabel and MyBtnONLabel.  Otherwise you need to be firing this RaisePropertyChanged somewhere else.. For example I would have expected to see a property in your example code for MyBtnChecked which would do this.  Then in your view model when MyBtnChecked is changed it would fire the RaisePropertyChanged event to mark it as checked or not when your ViewModel bool property is changed.